# ASP.Net C# Select Row in GridView without Updating the whole Page

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, pageload, selectedindex

I am trying to create some filter for my GridView. The filter is working fine but if I then select a column of the filtered GridView the whole page is refreshing...

Here my FilterCode:

```
protected void Filter_Berechtigung_DB_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<User> ll_UserList = new List<User>();

    foreach (var User in ReadZugriff())
    {
        if (User.Berechtigung.Contains(Filter_Berechtigung_DB.SelectedItem.Value))
        {
            ll_UserList.Add(User);
        }
    }
    // Läd die gefilterten Infos in das Datagrid
    LoadData(ll_UserList);
}
```

Here my LoadData:

```
private void LoadData(List<User> ll_UserList)
{
    UserTable.DataSource = ll_UserList;
    UserTable.DataBind();
}
```

I call the Method LoadData once at the start of the page load

Here my SelectedIndexChanged:

```
protected void UserTable_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var lv_Index = UserTable.SelectedIndex;

    UserTable.Rows[lv_Index].Style[HtmlTextWriterStyle.BackgroundColor] = "lightgray";
}
```

Here my GridView and the used buttons:

```
<div style="float: left">
    <ul>
        <li style="float: left; margin-right: 5px">Berechtigung:
        </li>
        <li style="float: left">
            <asp:DropDownList Style="height: 25px; width: 100px; font-size: 12px; margin-top: -2px" ID="Filter_Berechtigung_DB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Filter_Berechtigung_DB_SelectedIndexChanged">
                <asp:ListItem Text="" />
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<asp:GridView ID="UserTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserTable_SelectedIndexChanged" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black">
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="">
            <ItemStyle Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:BoundField>
        <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="lightgray" ForeColor="Black" />
    <RowStyle CssClass="TableItemHover" BackColor="White"></RowStyle>
    <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="gray" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
</asp:GridView>
```

Thanks for the help! I hope this is enough information to solve the task.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your `GridView` and `FilterDropDownList` into an [UpdatePanel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.updatepanel.aspx) to prevent all page postback:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="myUpdatePanel" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div style="float: left">
            <ul>
                <li style="float: left; margin-right: 5px">Berechtigung:
                </li>
                <li style="float: left">
                    <asp:DropDownList Style="height: 25px; width: 100px; font-size: 12px; margin-top: -2px" ID="Filter_Berechtigung_DB" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Filter_Berechtigung_DB_SelectedIndexChanged">
                        <asp:ListItem Text="" />
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <asp:GridView ID="UserTable" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Width="100%" CssClass="table table-striped table-bordered" OnSelectedIndexChanged="UserTable_SelectedIndexChanged" CellPadding="4" CellSpacing="2" ForeColor="Black">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField HeaderText="" DataField="">
                    <ItemStyle Font-Names="Arial" ForeColor="Black" />
                </asp:BoundField>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
            </Columns>
            <HeaderStyle BackColor="lightgray" ForeColor="Black" />
            <RowStyle CssClass="TableItemHover" BackColor="White"></RowStyle>
            <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="gray" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="Black" />
        </asp:GridView>
     </ContentTemplate>
     <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Filter_Berechtigung_DB" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UserTable" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />
     </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Comment: Line 163:                            <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="UserTable" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" /> Then I get an error because the program doesnt know the EventName Attribute

Comment: I have updated answer, please check again. `<asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="Filter_Berechtigung_DB" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged" />`

Comment: I am getting an error: The System.Web.UI.PostBackTrigger type has no public Attribute called EventName.

Comment: I just tried it with AsyncPostBackTrigger and it worked **BUT** if I select a filter and then press select on a row then the Gridview is Refreshing and the filter is not active anymore

Comment: Then you need to add another Trigger action, I have updated my answer. Please check

Comment: As soon I press the select column button in a Filtered row, the gridview refreshed and the SelectedUser is a driffrent

Comment: It's because you are changing data of gridview, so index is changed. That is another problem which is not related with this. You can ask another question with enough information.

Comment: As soon I apply a filter on my GridView the website has a white stripe at the bottom and the footer got pushed up because the Gridview has less Items than before. How to fix that?

Comment: Sorry but you should not ask all problem you have in one question. Please ask a question for each problem you have.